# VBA Word; How to resize bookmark label range?

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I have messed cross-references to pictures in my word document. The label shows only part of the figure name:
**Figure 5-**

I have found out that bookmark responsible for that has narrowed range than the full figure name:
**[Figure 5-]** 62: Caption text

I would like to extend the bookmark label up to ":" using VBA, but I have no idea how to go further with the code.
`Bookmark.Start` and `Bookmark.End` refer to the whole picture text so how to refer only to label? my code is as follow:

```
Sub extend_bookmarks()

    Dim bmk As Bookmark
    Dim msg As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    
    For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks


            If (InStr(1, bmk.Range.Text, "Figure") And IsNumeric(Mid(bmk.Range.Text, 8, 1))) Then
                pos = InStr(1, bmk.Range.Text, ":")
                If ((pos < 12) And (pos > 0)) Then
                    Debug.Print bmk.Name
                    Debug.Print bmk.Range.Text
                    Debug.Print bmk.End - bmk.Start; pos
                End If
            End If

    Next bmk

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just  reapply the bookmark using the paragraph it sits in as the range.

```
Sub extend_bookmarks()

    Dim bmk As Variant
    
    For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=bmk.range.Paragraphs(1).range, Name := bmk.Name

    Next

End Sub
```

Update, When I tested the code above I only stepped through the loop twice and so missed the obvious, that you cannot use 'for each' when you are changing the content of a collection.

The code below correctly extends the bookmarks as intended and does not crash word.

```
Sub extend_bookmarks()

    Dim myCount As Long
    myCount = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count
    
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    
        For myIndex = myCount To 1 Step -1
    
            .Add Range:=.Item(myIndex).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range, Name:=.Item(myIndex).Name
    
        Next
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not work as expected. Actually it hangs Word.

Comment: Apologies for that.  Updated code and explanation is provided.